# ping in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ping

I want to make a ping in my project. I have already tried the `ping-litle` library but it is not working. I also tried this :

```
var request = new xhtmlrequest();
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (request.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    }

    if (request.status === 200) {
         console.log('success'); 
    } else {
         console.log('error'); 
    }
 };

request.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.254/'); 
request.send();
```

But when I call the function a second time I have the same result even if my host is disconnected.
Have you an idea to make a good ping in React Native ?
or how to destroy my `xhtmlrequest` ?

Comment: You probably wanted to write: `new XMLHttpRequest()`

Comment: This will basically check if there is a running http server on port 80 on the remote IP, it's not a PING. A computer can be pingable without having a server an http server on port 80 as well as it might ignore ping queries while having a running http server. Best example is the 4.2.2.2 DNS server often used to check if you have access to internet. If you can PING it (with a PING query) you can tell you have access internet, but this server will not respond to an http request on port 80.

Comment: Now to answer your question, there is a react-native-ping plugin, even if I don't find it very stable.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [fetch API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) which is provided by react-native.

Your code would look like this:

```
fetch('http://192.168.0.254')
  .then((response) => {
     if (response.status === 200) {
       console.log('success');
     } else {
       console.log('error');
     }
   })
  .catch((error) => {
       console.log('network error: ' + error);
   })
```